# Text in UItextview doesn't fit iPhone screen

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uitextview

I am a new to iOS programming 
I am trying to make Text to be shown on all the screen of the iPhone 
I use UItextview it look nice when I am in the programming mode, once I run the simulator it looks wired like that --

Here is the image 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Csx7r.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need constraints to have the textview fit the bounds of the screen. Here is a great tutorial on how constraints work. http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1